# How to group by a last letter in a column

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, dplyr, data-visualization

I was to create a graph for my assignment that should be a line plot based on last letters of values of one column. For example:

```
data <- data.frame(c('apple', 'banana', 'pie', 'fries', 'tomato', 'cheese'))

data %>%
 group_by(here i should group by names ending with the same last letter) 
 ...
```

Above is just the outline and an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I looked for a solution but couldn't find one. What is the solution to this?

Thanks in prior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_sub()` :

```r
data %>%
 group_by(last_letter = stringr::str_sub(column, -1, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of other options -

1. With `substring` -

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(col = c('apple', 'banana', 'pie', 'fries', 'tomato', 'cheese'))
data %>% group_by(grp = substring(col, nchar(col)))
```

2. Using `sub` -

```
data %>% group_by(grp = sub('.*(.)$', '\\1', col))
```

Comment: you have provided a working solution as well but the other one was simpler and given earlier, so I have to accept that as the current answer. But I will upvote this as well. thank you

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
    group_by(grp = str_replace(col, ".*(.)$", "\\1"))
```